# matrix of squares of elements of another matrix

Tags: matrices

What is the correct way to show that a matrix is equal to the squares of each element of another matrix? (In MATLAB it would be B = A.^2 but what is the mathematical way of indicating this?

Comment: As written your sentence makes no sense

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want 'Suppose $$A = (a_{ij}), B = (b_{ij}) \in k^{m \times n} $$
where for all $1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n$, $$b_{ij} = a_{ij}^2?$$

Comment: Thank you - that conveys what I wanted. I wondered if there was a standard mathematical way to write this but maybe there isn't.

Comment: If there is one, I hadn't yet heard of it, but the Hadamard square in Shogun's comment seems to do the trick. But as it's unlikely everyone will have heard of it, why not just spell it out?